# How to Reference default CodeCommit output location in CloudFormation template

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

Lets say we create CodePipeline called "Win-UrgentProject-Dev" with a bucket for the pipeline is set to:
pipelines-123456

Next we set up a CodeCommit action that has an output called "Source" that feeds into a CodeBuild project.

When this pipeline is triggered, the source snapshot is stored in:
s3://pipelines-123456/Win-UrgentProject-De/Source/915xgov

The location is automagically determined to be:
bucket_name/pipeline_name(truncated to 20 characters)/source_output_name/unique_generated_id

Now I would like my BuildProject to store it's output in (the reason is long and uninteresting, please just go with the requirement):
s3://pipelines-123456/Win-UrgentProject-De/artifact_v1.0.0.zip

However I can't find a way in CloudFormation to reference this location.  I could hard-code it as a template parameter, but this seems brittle as anyone changing any names within the template will also need to know/remember to update the template parameter.

Is there some way to reference the default CodeCommit-Output-Location in your CloudFormation template?  Perhaps I could parse that to strip away the last 2 segments (Source/915xgov)?

Comment: When you say 'CloudFormation template' it's not clear if you mean the template your code pipeline definition is declared in or in a template deployed in a subsequent stage or action in your pipeline, you need to be more explicit.

Comment: Hi @RonanCunningham, yes my pipeline/build project are all part of the same cloud formation template

Comment: That location is used internally by code pipeline to manage it's artefacts,there is no way I know to refer to it programmatically. Asking technologists to just go with the requirement, good luck with that. I would question your need to store it with that name in that location - are you aware of how different actions in a pipeline use InputArtifacts and OutputArtifacts to pass files between each other and how to pass Namespaced variables? I've yet to come across a scenario where they couldn't solve problems of passing data within the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, I'm using all the things you mentioned, however the output artifact must derive it's name from the version of the app being built (so I can't specify it at the time the cloudformation sets everything up) and the place where it is stored is also specific because the existing deployment infrastructure expects it to be there.  I can't change that without affecting all the other pipelines in my organization (and that's not going to get approved).

Comment: I would not have done things this way, but sometimes you have to work with the hand you are dealt.  Right now I am exploring using OverrideArtifactName to set the output name from the BuildSpec and using a Lambda Transform to set the 'Location' of the artifact by combining the Bucket URI (which I do know ahead of time) with the AWS::StackName.